# How to initialize the core Timer in an ARM Cortex-A7

Tags: timer, operating-system, arm

Currently, I'm working on developing an Operative System for Raspberry 2, it's my final project to obtain my University degree, and right now I'm having severe problems to create a simple timer that throws an interrupt each second because the [documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.subset.cortexa.cortexa7/index.html) provided by ARM doesn't clarify how to initialize that module.
I read the architectural reference manual, it's in *ARM architecture/Reference manuals/ARMv7-AR*

Can someone explain to me how it is the process of initializing a core timer?

I will adjunct what I tried so far:

In my C file

```
    _local_timer_init();
    // ROUTING IRQ
    *(volatile uint32_t*)CORE0_L_TIMER_INT_CTL = 0x8;
```

In my assemble file

```
.globl _local_timer_init
/*
        THIS STEPS APPLIES IN A SYSTEM WHERE THERE IS NOT VIRTUALIZATION SUPPORT
        (I think so)
    1. Look into CNTKCTL register if you need
    2. Look into CNTP_CTL or CNTH_CTL or CNTV_CTL to enable or disable
       the corresponding timer (bit 0)
    3. You have to set the compare value for the corresponding timer
       CNTP_CVAL, CNTH_CVAL, CNTV_CVAL if needed
    4. It should be in boot.S but you have to initialize the counter 
       frequency register, CNTFRQ
    5. Putting the corresponding TVAL register to a right value
    6. Routing the IRQ and enabling IRQ of the corresponding core
*/
_local_timer_init:
    // ENABLING TIMER
    mov r0, #1
    mcr p15, #0, r0, c14, c3, #1 //Write to CNTV_CTL
    // SETTING FREQUENCY TIMER
    //we don't need this right now
    // SETTING TVAL REGISTER (virtual)
    mrc p15, #0, r0, c14, c0, #0 //we obtain CNTFRQ
    mcr p15, #0, r0, c14, c3, #0 //Write to CNTV_TVAL
```

I also created my custom assemble handler for IRQ exceptions like this:
maybe the problem is here, I really don't know Is this the correct way to handle an IRQ exception?

```
irq_s_handler:
    /*Mode: PL1 irq */
    srsda sp!, #0x12 //we stores the spsr and lr at the address contained in sp of the mode irq
    /*
    It is necessary to switch to supervisor mode and store some registers
    into it's stack for having support for nested exceptions
     */
    push {r0-r12}
    bl irq_c_handler
    pop {r0-r12}
    rfeib sp! //we do the inverse operation of srsdb
    subs pc, lr, #4 //we adjust the appropiate value considered
```

Comment: did you try polling first?  always start with polling if you can, understand as much of the peripheral as you can before enabling it through to the interrupt controller, then poll as much as you can there, before enabling that through to interrupt the processor.  Trying to do it all at once usually fails and takes longer to figure out.

Comment: are you required to use a timer in the core or can any timer in the chip be used?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for the long delay, I just figured out what was happening, it wasn't problem of any of the code showed above, it was problem of one my c files elsewhere, I feel dumb right now but I resolved my problem. Thank you for trying to help me old_timer anyways, your idea will help me to solve my next problem, understand the mailbox of arm cortex a7 :)